# Filename length in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, filenames

When I try to save my files to Windows Explorer, I get an error message that states (in part): "filenames too long." The file names have been between 100 and 200 characters. My task is to include a fair amount of information in the Explorer file name.

I've been asking questions and researching, and understand that it's necessary to allow for the drive designation characters, the folders and sub-folders, and so on. I get that.

Once that's all taken into account, though, I'm still not sure what my parameters are for the number of characters to allocate for the specific file names.

Must I abbreviate my words with barbaric ruthlessness to keep the total way <100? Or am I able to spell most words out properly, thus exceeding 100? Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: wow, I'm sometimes amazed at how much perspectives can vary. Its long filenames (especially those with spaces <cringe />) that I find barbaric. Either way, since you were originally limited to 8.3 character filenames, a 64.3 character name (8x the FAT standard) would seem more than reasonable, considering.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your filesystem and used codepage in filenames.
See limits here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681827%28VS.85%29.aspx#limits

```
Maximum file name length
NTFS                   | exFAT                  | UDF                                 | FAT32
255 Unicode characters | 255 Unicode characters | 127 Unicode or 254 ASCII characters | 255 Unicode characters
```

Comment: Also note that with older FAT based filesystems, There is a limit to the number of files you can store that consist of longer than 8 characters, such that the total number of characters for filenames in ALL files within a directory combined cannot exceed 8x256. I once met a lady who filled up her entire floppy's name table with 3 files that had absurdly long names.

Comment: It’s not clear that this addresses the OP’s problem, as she says “The filenames have been between 100 and 200 characters.”, so the 255 character limit shouldn’t be an issue.  [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at the Windows Dev Center) says, “In the Windows API (with some exceptions …), the maximum length for a path is **MAX_PATH**, which is defined as 260 characters.  A path [includes] drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character.”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and “The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters [with] components [of length up to] 255 characters.”